# python get number of occurences of given pattern in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as following:

```
adict = {'instr1' : "yes", 'instr2' : "yes", 'instr3' : "yes", 'instr4' : "no"}
```

Is there an easy method to get the number of "yes" in the dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> adict = {'instr1' : "yes", 'instr2' : "yes", 'instr3' : "yes", 'instr4' : "no"}
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(adict.values())
Counter({'yes': 3, 'no': 1})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sum` and a generator expression:

```
>>> sum(1 for x in adict.itervalues() if x == 'yes')
3
```

As `True == 1`, so this is also valid:

```
sum( x == 'yes' for x in adict.itervalues())
```

Another option is `list.count`, this is going to be fast compared to `sum()`, but creates a list of all values in the memory:

```
>>> adict.values().count('yes')
3
```